# android project not getting built

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am a newbie to Android development, and am using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo on Ubuntu 11.10. I have the SDK and the ADT installed. I have two problems.

1. An Android project takes an awfully long time to get created.
2. When I restart Eclipse, all previously built Projects (even simple Hello World ones) have to be rebuilt, and this takes a really long time to build. While building the "details" dialog box shows

   `Loading data for Android 2.3.3`

   `Android 2.3.3: Widgets and Layouts`

then,

`Building Workspace` (where the progress bar seems to remain halted for eternity). At times it gets built after this. At other times, the first line in the HelloAndroid.java file shows an error, which when rebuilt *yet* again disappears.

So when I restart Eclipse, it takes approximately 10 minutes to get previously built projects running on the Emulator.

Any fixes to this?

Comment: What's the error that's being displayed?

Comment: When I restart Eclipse, the error that appears below the console : Unable to resolve target 'android-10' until the SDK is loaded.

Comment: I would try reinstall eclipse and Android SDK again. It seems something went wrong (assuming your machine has recommended capacity).

Comment: and the one that appears after the first rebuild is 

"the type java.Lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly references from required .class file." against the first line which is the declaration of the package.

Comment: reinstall eclipse and the SDK again? Setting it all up took a really long time ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Hard telling what the issue is without more information, but here are some thoughts:

1. Your machine may be underpowered. What OS, processor speed, RAM do you have?
2. If you have a very large amount of projects, or have some very large projects, then it can take a long time to build them when Eclipse starts. You can close a project (right-click the project in Package Explorer and click Close Project) so it will not be built and is not accessible until you open it later. Close projects you aren't actively working on, but may want to use again someday in the future.
3. The ADV (emulator) takes a long, long time to start up, yes. When you start it, make sure to select the option to start from snapshot and save to snapshot to save time starting it in the future.

And yes, you may want to reinstall everything again. Sometimes Eclipse just gets screwy.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 11.10. Laptop is Dell Inspiron 1545 running Intel Core 2 Duo, Processor speed is 2.2 GHz, RAM is 3 GB.

Comment: That should be powerful enough then. Sorry, shoo, I'm not thinking of anything except for the ideas I've already mentioned. Maybe someone who knows more about Ubuntu specifically can help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like any of several items were improperly installed.  Consequently, the directories of where your compiled libraries can't be found and must be regenerated each time.  That is why it takes ten minutes or more: you're recompiling *everything*!

The time it will take for you to track everything down and repair the settings will be MUCH longer than the time to just do a fresh install.

Really.

Comment: OK, so if I know someone who has the SDK and ADT and the various platforms properly downloaded and install, then can I copy his folders to my computer install of downloading again?

Comment: I'm guessing that it might.  Can't hurt to try.  Let us know if you succeeded.